# moment js calculate time diffrence from now to date

Tags: node.js, express, momentjs

I'm new to all the developing stuff and, I need to calculate the time difference between now and a later date.

Below is the code I have written but for some reason it doesn't show the correct time difference.

I think that the problem lies in the `now = moment();`
because I debugged it a lot
can anyone help

```
var express = require('express');
var moment = require('moment');
var app = express();

app.get('/from/:day/:month/:year', function (req, res) {
    var now = moment();

    var urlDate = req.params;
    var dateJSON = JSON.stringify(urlDate);
    var obj = JSON.parse(dateJSON);

    var final = moment([obj.year, obj.month, obj.day]);

    var years = final.diff(now, 'year');
    now.add(years, 'years');

    var months = final.diff(now, 'months');
    now.add(months, 'months');

    var days = final.diff(now, 'days');

    console.log(years + ' years ' + months + ' months ' + days + ' days');
    res.send(years + ' years ' + months + ' months ' + days + ' days');
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your date format is wrong. You can use the default date format which is: YYYY-MM-DD

So

```
var final = moment(`${obj.year}-${obj.month}-${obj.day}`);
var years = final.diff(now, 'year');
    now.add(years, 'years');
```

Note: You don't have to stringify and parse. It is already an object

```
var urlDate = req.params;
    //var dateJSON = JSON.stringify(urlDate);
    //var obj = JSON.parse(dateJSON);
year=urlDate.year
```

Comment: the console says that this will be decapitated in the next major release

Comment: yes use some other format. i just suggested how to solve the problem or issue with ur code